# Unrecognised Database Format in VS2013

Tags: ms-access

Whenever I attempt to add an ACCDB connection in visual studio 2013 I get an error message saying "unrecognised database format". This applies to any accdb file, not just the one I made. I'm using the OLD DB connection option.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: *"I'm using the OLD DB connection option."* - Does that mean you are using `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`?

Comment: Yeah, it just decided to work after I opened a different project, closed it and opened the original one again... weird